# Generating a random grade and labeling it properly

Tags: java

I'm only about 3 weeks into learning java in college, so assume I don't know anything because any tips at all would help. Anyway, I'm trying to do this question:

"Write a Java program that generates a random number between 0 and 100 (representing a grade). The program then, on separate lines, prints out the generated grade followed by the corresponding letter grade (A, B, C, D, F) using the standard scale below. Label your output properly and use escape characters to lineup the outputs after the labels."

```
90 – 100: A
80 – 89:  B
70 – 79:  C
60 – 69:  D
00 – 59:  F
```

What I have so far is this:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Practice_3_2
{

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        final int max = 100;
        int answer, grade;
        int A = 90;

        Random generator = new Random(); // random number generator object

        answer = generator.nextInt(max) + 1;

        if (grade >= A); {
            System.out.println ("That grade is an A.");
        }
    }
}
```

I enter a grade below 90 but the if statement becomes true anyway.

Comment: I'm confused; what part does the `Scanner` play in this?

Comment: Ah, it's leftover code from the example my teacher left, I'll take that out.

Comment: Your `if` statement doesn't work because there's an `;` before the `{`. The line before the `if` statement uses the `scan` you just removed.

Comment: Your current question isn't a well formulated question, but rather is a "here are some requirements and here is some code", without explaining where or how you're stuck. Moving forward, please check out the [help] section on [asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to see how to improve this and future questions.

Comment: Sorry, that was also leftover code @Andreas

Comment: `nextInt(100)` returns a number between `0` and `99`. `nextInt(100) + 1` will then be a number between `1` and `100`. Your grade scale goes from **`0` to `100`**, so you're a number short.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I added the problem I'm having at the bottom.

Comment: @royal422 See my first comment about the `;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a scanner. Nothing in the requirements asks for user input.

To generate a number between 0 and 101 you need:

```
answer = generator.nextInt(max + 1);
```

Once you have generated your random score, you need to figure out where on the grade scale that fits. The simplest way is to use a series of `if else` statements.

```
System.out.println("Score: " + answer);
int A = 90;
int B = 80;
int C = 70;
int D = 60;
System.out.print("Grade: ");
if(answer >= A) {
    System.out.println("A");
} else if(answer >= B) {
    System.out.println("B");
} else if(answer >= C) {

    ...

} else {
    System.out.println("F");
}
```

Comment: Requirements are unclear in this area. Have added labels.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track, except for a few things.

1. `answer = generator.nextInt(max) + 1;` will not include zero
2. no need for scanner, as it will generate a random number.

Try this:

```
    Random gen = new Random();

    int grade= gen.nextInt(101);
    if(90 <= grade && grade <= 100){
       System.out.println("The grade is A");

    }else if(80 <= grade && grade <= 89){
       System.out.println("The grade is B");

    }else if () //and so forth
```

Comment: Checking upper boundary is excessive.